# Regex - remove any number of commas at the end of a line

Tags: c#, regex

Alright, Regex gurus, how can I change my logic to fix this one?

I've made a regex:

```
(,[,]+)
```

It's supposed to remove extra commas on the end of a line. (end of line being \r\n) when formatted as a string.

It works (sort of).

This is the string:

```
Date,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24,\r\nDate,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24,,,,,\r\nDate,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24,,,,,\r\nDate,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24,,\r\n
```

When I run that regex, it gives a result of:

```
Date,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24,\r\nDate,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24\r\nDate,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24\r\nDate,1-Jul-18,1-Jul-19,1-Jul-20,1-Jul-21,1-Jul-22,1-Jul-23,1-Jul-24\r\n
```

I need to remove the comma at the end of the first line (I think I need to be finding \r\n and killing any commas before that, until a non-comma.

Any thoughts about how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you working in?

Answer (score 5):

`(,+$)` perhaps? (One or more commas followed immediately by the end of a line.)

Answer (score 1):

If your language supports positive lookahead, try this -

```
([,]*)(?=\\r\\n)
```

Comment: Now that I know you're using C#, I can also confirm that positive lookahead is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can match one or more `,` followed by `\r\n` by using  `,+\\r\\n`. Don't know how to replace that using C# sorry. In perl I would do

```
perl -pi -e 's/,+\\r\\n/\\r\\n/g' c.txt
```

(assuming that `c.txt` is a file containing your input text).